# Why authentication provider when implementing basic auth? Spring Security

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

Right now, i am trying to learn basic authentication + database using Spring security.
I have done the implementation of both UserDetails and UserDetailsService(here i fetch the user from the db) and used the decorator pattern to use my own "User" Bean. Everything works as it should work.

Now, the thing that i noticed in many examples on different forums, platforms is that when developers implement basic auth + db in spring they use the AuthenticationProvider which made me a confused!
A simple example of what i have seen:

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider());

    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return provider;
    }
```

IS THERE ANY SPECIFIC GOOD REASON TO DO THIS or is there any new feature in spring security that already covers this kind of implementation "behind the scenes".
As I said my application works as it should without this kind of implementation.
That's why I am asking if anyone has a good explanation.

Comment: You can also use `auth.userDetailsService` which would yield the same result

Comment: Yes, i did that too after i tried with authenticationProvider. But the thing is that it works without that also. So why should i use that?

Comment: You have some sort of authentication provider, if you leave it out, it will only use the default in-memory one with a default user. It will not use your database.

Comment: NOPE! It uses the ones that i have saved on my database. It is already tested.

Comment: Then you have disabled the Spring Boot auto-config (by adding `@EnableWebSecurity`) and have added the `UserDetailsService` as a bean (either manually or through component-scanning). I believe newer versions of Spring Security detect a single `UserDetailsService` and use that automatically, older versions didn't.

Comment: Yes, i have done the implementation of UserDetailsService. I think that is as you are saying. Maybe newer versions of Spring Sec... detect the UserDetailsService. I just wanted to double-check.Thanks

Comment: I have a PasswordEncoder Bean that i use but i don't need to explicitly add that to the authenticationProvider.

Comment: It will detect the decoder and else use the delegating one. Detection of single beans has been added somewhere along the way for Java based config, to make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `InitializeUserDetailsBeanManagerConfigurer.java`,

It has the following snippet and wires them:

```
UserDetailsService userDetailsService = getBeanOrNull(UserDetailsService.class);
...
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = getBeanOrNull(PasswordEncoder.class);
....
DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
if (passwordEncoder != null) {
   provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
...
auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
```

So your comments makes sense. I.e by defining a `userDetailsService` and `passwordEncoder` beans, they are detected by spring security and `autowired`

Comment: Yeap. Checked it. It does set the userDetailsService by default together with the PasswordEncoder if there already are beans/components. Thanks.

Comment: This can be done since Spring Security 4.1.0, according to the changelogs. So it isn't that new, before that you  needed the more verbose edition. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3088